# auto complete title tags

Tags: jquery, href, title

Not sure if this is possible and could just be crazy easter monday boredom! But just thought it could save me some hassle.

Im wondering if when you link some text that text could be duplicated in the title tag, ie:

```
<a href="#" title="these are the words" >these are the words</a>
```

Could jquery do this? Something like look for text in  and duplicate in title?

Comment: `$("a").attr("title", $("a").text());` ? The questions are: does a contains only text and no html? Maybe you'd like to invoke it on click? etc.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Please don't say SEO.

Comment: Hi Rich,

Not really, im starting to learn jQuery and it was just an idea I wanted to explore. If used in the right places why wouldnt you use this  from a SEO perspective ie: A Blog title in a Wordpress theme or in navigation. Of course if you link says "click here" that wouldnt be very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all of the links using this code:

```
 $('a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('title', text );
});
```

The first part gets the link text and then it makes the title that text.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this could be done.

```
$(function() {
   $("a").each(function(index, element) {
     $(element).attr('title',$(element).text());
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks all, some great help, im just starting out with jquery and your  answers are helping me understand what is possible, Rich raised a point about SEO, I would be interested to get feedback on the above post.

Comment: to address what @rich said, search engines usually don't parse/execute  JavaScript, so if you added the title tags w/ jQuery, they still wouldn't be present as far as the search engine is concerned.

Comment: Ah, i didnt know that so it would be pointless in that respect, thanks.